# How to prevent ng-model to override value of input text generated by directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have directive to set some values of form

```
lightconsole.directive("injectSession", function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var paramInput = angular.element(element).find("input")
        if (paramInput) {
            var paramName = scope.param.name.toLowerCase();
            var sessHolder = angular.element("#user_session");
            if (paramName === "session" || paramName == "sessionid") {
                paramInput.val(sessHolder.val());
                sessHolder.bind("change", function (session) {
                    paramInput.val(sessHolder.val());
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

then I created a `form` with `ng-repeat`:

```
<form ng-submit="callFun()">
    <table class="materail_input_block">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="param in fun.operationArguments" inject-session>
            <td>{{param.type}}</td>
            <td>{{param.name}}</td>
            <td><input name="{{param.name}}"
                       class="form-control materail_input" type="text"
                       placeholder="enter value"/></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Call"/>
</form> );
```

In this case, everything works fine if one of the element is named session, value form hidden input is set as input value, but when I add `ng-model` to the `input` element then value is erased.

Comment: remove paramInput and use the scope like `scope.myModel = sessHolder.val()` and on input just add `ng-model="myModel"`

Comment: Thank You @JoseRocha that work well. But could u please explain why setting value on input element didnt work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to write this as answer but it was too long to do it as comment.
This probably is not the best explanation that i can give, but basically you were mixing jquery/javascript with angular. When you define in some input a `ng-model` the `scope` will watch every change on that `ng-model` to the `scope.model` that you give to him so to modify the value in code you have to change the `scope.model` trying to change it with javascript will not update the `scope.model` so will not "trigger" the scope.watch.

You can see this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873627/angularjs-ng-model-binding-not-updating-when-changed-with-jquery) if you want to apply changes by javascript to angular scope.

But i since you are using angular i would recommend to resolve every possible thing with angular and not mix.