# Angular: how to update non-angular javascript variable in response to a change of scope model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've a huge jQuery plugin with domain logic from a third-party team and I really don't want to mess with its guts. This plugin exposes an object called `browser` to the global namespace.

I have a simple Angular controller. I made it `$watch()` the changes of `browser` (using object equality, not referential equality) and update the scope accordingly:

```
$scope.$watch(browser, function(newValue, oldValue, scope) { scope.browser = newValue; }, true);
```

Fine, but now I need to do the reverse: I need to update the global `browser` object when `$scope.browser` model changes in the course of Angular's `$digest` loop. How do I do that?

Probably, I need to create a custom hook to Angular's dirty-checking loop. I understand, that this is a bad approach and that the whole point of two-way binding was to avoid these manual callbacks, but I just can't figure out a better solution.

Comment: I think it will be helps to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873627/angularjs-ng-model-binding-not-updating-when-changed-with-jquery

Comment: @RameshRajendran Thank you. Yes, I understand that any changes of scope from non-angular event handlers should be wrapped by `$apply()` call. But this is a different case, I believe, I need to create a custom hook for Angular's dirty checking loop. And I understand, this is an abuse and bad design and Angular was created to avoid this, but can't figure out a better solution anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can reverse back as the same way

```
$scope.$watch("browser", function(newValue, oldValue, scope) { browser = newValue; }, true);
```

Comment: So, you mean that by watching `browser`, Angular will automatically change it, if, for example, some directive modified it in UI? So, essentially, browser works as if it were a part of `$scope`? Cool, but how can I let directive access `browser` variable, it's out of `$scope`?